# Adding Historical Imagery on BaseMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-online-basemaps

In adding Basemap, aside the types of map provided, is there any way I can add historical imagery?

Comment: Your question is unclear - are you asking if there are historical basemaps available? Or how to add your own historical imagery?  Or are you asking for a source of historical imagery that you can add?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  In ArcMap use Add Data from ArcGIS Online (on the Standard toolbar) and then use a search string of "historical imagery" to locate a number of sources:

[image]